# What would irreducible character mean if the characteristic of a field is not zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, definition

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ be an algebraically closed field such that $char(F)$ does not divide $|G|$.

Let $\chi_1,\chi_2$ be the characters corresponding to representations $(\rho_1,V_1),(\rho_2,V_2)$ respectively.

If $\chi_1=\chi_2$, then are $(\rho_1,V_1)$ and $(\rho_2,V_2)$ isomorphic?

(I only know that this is true when the given field $F$ has characteristic $0$, (not necessarily algebraically closed.))

This must not be true, because if $L$ is a simple $F[G]$ module and $char(F)\neq 0$, then two $F[G]$ modules $M=L, N=L\oplus\cdots\oplus L$($1 + char(F)$ times) have the same character, but are not isomorphic as $F[G]$-modules.

So there are two possible definitions for irreducible characters:

> 1. A character is irreducible if it is the character of some simple $F[G]$-module.
> 2. A character is irreducible if it is not a pointwise sum of two nonzero characters.

These two are obviously equivalent when $char(F)=0$, but I'm not sure whether these are equivalent when $F$ is algebraically closed and $|G|$ is not divisible by $char(F)$.

Comment: I am not sure why one would want to define "irreducible character" in any way that was not equivalent to "character of an irreducible representation". Under your definition (2), for example, wouldn't the trivial character of any group be not-irreducible in characteristic $5$ , as we'd have $1=(1+1+1)+(1+1+1)$ as you've already seen.